# Search pattern in string using regex in obj-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, regex, pattern-matching

I'm working on a string pattern match algorithm. I use NSRegularExpression for finding the matches. For ex: I've to find all words starting with '#' in a string.. 
Currently I use the following regex function:

```
static NSRegularExpression *_searchTagRegularExpression;
static inline NSRegularExpression * SearchTagRegularExpression() 
{
     if (!_searchTagRegularExpression) 
     {
          _searchTagRegularExpression = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] 
                                          initWithPattern:@"(?<!\\w)#([\\w\\._-]+)?"
                                                  options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive 
                                                    error:nil];
     }

     return _searchTagRegularExpression;
}
```

and I use it as below:

```
NSString *searchString = @"Hi, #Hash1 #Hash2 #Hash3...";
NSRange searchStringRange = NSMakeRange(0, searchString.length);
NSRegularExpression *regexp = SearchTagRegularExpression();
[regexp enumerateMatchesInString:searchString 
                         options:0 
                           range:searchStringRange 
                      usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
{       
  // comes here for every match with range ( in this case thrice )
}];
```

This works properly. But i just want to know if this is the best way. suggest if there's any better alternative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your proposed pattern and implementation is quite good:

- The pattern is quite precise with its use of the (fancy) zero-width negative look behind assertion to make sure you only match at the beginning of a word. It works correctly at the beginning of a string, for example.
- The implementation reuses the regex object and avoids recompilation of the pattern.

If you wanted me to be nitpicking: You could drop the `NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive` option as your pattern does not use any parts that have a case.

Comment: Thnks for the input.. i should try removing caseinsensitive search and log the time to see the difference !!!

Answer (score -1):

What you do is a good way for sure. You can do this too,

```
for(NSString *match in [string componentSeperatedByString:@" "])
    {
      if([match hasPrefix:@"#"])
       {
         //do what you like.
        }
     }
```

Comment: No. That would match any character as a word character (including punctuation and such). It would also match single # characters.